# Inequality of convex function with Lipschitz continuous gradient

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I am interested in proving the following inequality for a convex function $g$ with $L$-Lipschitz continuous gradient:

> For $\alpha \in [0,1]$, $$g(\alpha x + (1- \alpha)y) \leq \alpha g(x) + (1-\alpha)g(y) - \frac{\alpha (1-\alpha)}{2 L} \left\| \nabla g(x) - \nabla g(y) \right\|^2 $$

I have tried to apply the definitions of convexity but have not been able to prove this.

Comment: L-Lipschitz continuous gradient means $\|\nabla g(x) - \nabla g(y)\|\le L\|x-y\|$?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means.

Comment: **Hint**: Try proving the following lower bound first:

$$
g(y) \geq g(x) + \langle \nabla g(x), y - x \rangle +
\frac{1}{2L} \| \nabla g(x) - \nabla g(y) \|^2, \; \forall y, x.
$$

Comment: I tried doing this, but wasn't able to, do you have a hint for the hint?

Comment: @RJon: I added a proof sketch for the hint. Happy to add more context if/when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: your claim will follow from the following lower bound:

> **Lemma**: if $g$ is convex and $L$-smooth, then for any $x, y$ we have
> $$
> g(y) \geq g(x) + \langle \nabla g(x), y - x \rangle + \frac{1}{2L} \lVert \nabla g(x) - \nabla g(y) \rVert^2.
> $$

**Proof sketch**: note that since $g$ is $L$-smooth, it satisfies

$$
g(y) \leq g(x) + \langle \nabla g(x), y - x \rangle + \frac{L}{2} \lVert y -x \rVert^2
$$

Let $h(y) := g(y) - \langle \nabla g(x), y \rangle$, which is also convex and $L$-smooth (why?) and minimized at $x$. Then:

$$
h(x) \leq \min_{z} h(z)
\overset{(\text{smoothness})}{\leq} \min_{z} \left\{ h(y) + \langle \nabla h(y), z - y \rangle + \frac{L}{2}
\lVert y - z \rVert^2 \right\}
$$

Try finding the minimizer in the expression on the RHS above and rearranging, and you obtain the lemma.

Comment: I still don’t much understand, why does the final conclusion follows directly from the lower bound lemma?

Comment: @Ho-Oh: You have to apply the lower bound lemma twice around the point $\alpha x + (1 - \alpha)y$ and do some algebra, but that's about it.

Comment: Thanks! This is because letting $z=\alpha x+(1-\alpha)y$,$g(x) \geq g(z) + \langle \nabla g(z), x - z \rangle + \frac{1}{2L} \lVert \nabla g(z) - \nabla g(x) \rVert^2$, $g(y) \geq g(z) + \langle \nabla g(z), y - z \rangle + \frac{1}{2L} \lVert \nabla g(z) - \nabla g(y) \rVert^2$, multiplying the first inequality with $\alpha$ and second inequality with $1-\alpha$ and adding them together yields the result.