# Convex function inequalities with gradient being Lipschitz continuous, starting from $f(y)\le f(x)+(\nabla f(x))^T(y-x)+\frac{L}{2}\Vert y-x\Vert_2^2$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f$ be a continuously differentiable convex function defined on $\mathbb R^n$, i.e., $f :\mathbb R^n \rightarrow\mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable and for any $x,y \in\mathbb R^n$ and any $\alpha\in (0,1)$, $f(\alpha x + (1 -\alpha)y) \le \alpha f(x) + (1 -\alpha)f(y)$. Suppose that the gradient of $f$ is Lipschitz continuous, i.e., there exists a constant $L > 0$ such that
$$\Vert\nabla f(x)-\nabla f(y)\Vert_2\le L\Vert x-y\Vert_2.$$
Prove the following inequalities:
\begin{array}
((1).f(y)\le f(x)+(\nabla f(x))^T(y-x)+\frac{L}{2}\Vert y-x\Vert_2^2,~~~\forall x,y\in\mathbb R^n \\ (2).f(y)\ge f(x)+(\nabla f(x))^T(y-x)+\frac{1}{2L}\Vert \nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\Vert_2^2,~~~\forall x,y\in\mathbb R^n\\ (3).\frac{1}{L}\Vert \nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x)\Vert_2^2\le(\nabla f(y)-\nabla f(x))^T(y-x),~~~\forall x,y\in\mathbb R^n
\end{array}
$$$$
For the 1-dim case this is not hard, just use the Taylor expansion and the Lipschitz property can derive the whole 3 inequality. However, I don't know how to extend the results into $\mathbb R^n$ since I don't know how to deal with the 2-norms here. I think there're ways to deal with such kind of problem in convex analysis that I don't know. Are there any solutions or suggestions of solving these inequality? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This may be helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433024/inequality-of-convex-function-with-lipschitz-continuous-gradient/

Comment: In the general dimensional case, the key identity is

$$
f(y) - f(x) = \int_{0}^{1} \langle \nabla f(x + t(y - x)), y - x \rangle \text{d}t,
$$

which follows after noticing that $f(y) = h(1)$ and $f(x) = h(0)$ for the univariate function
$$
h(t) = f(x + t(y - x)).
$$

Comment: Check the book by Amir Beck or by C. Zalinescu. This is standard stuff.