# Property of differentiable functions with Lipschitz gradient

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to prove that, given $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable and convex with a Lipschitz gradient, then there exists $\alpha>0$ such that $f(x-\alpha\nabla f(x)) \leq f(x)$.

With regard to the condition of $||\nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)|| \leq L ||x-y||$, I have read some posts such as [Inequality of convex function with Lipschitz continuous gradient](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4433024/inequality-of-convex-function-with-lipschitz-continuous-gradient) related to the problem but I don't know how to apply those reasonings here. Any hint? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following quadratic upper bound given in one of the answers to the question you referred to $$f(y)\leq f(x) + \nabla f(x)^T(y - x) + \frac{L}{2}||y-x||^2$$ which holds for any $x,y$. If we set $y = x - \alpha\nabla f(x)$ then we obtain $$f(x - \alpha\nabla f(x))\leq f(x) + \left(\alpha^2\frac{L}{2}-\alpha\right)||\nabla f(x)||^2$$ which implies that if $0\leq \alpha\leq 2/L$, then $f(x - \alpha\nabla f(x))\leq f(x)$.